# ¿Cuál sería la traducción correcta para 'which', usada para especificar?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

Estaba pensando en el uso inglés de 'which' no como relativo, tampoco como pregunta, sino más bien para especificar, o enfatizar, una cosa a la que ya había referencia.

Mi diccionario da el ejemplo

> he refused, which decision proved disastrous
>
> *se negó, decisión que resultó desastrosa*

lo que significa, a mi entender, que no hay una palabra especifica que se use aquí para 'which'.  ¿O es la ausencia de 'una' aquí lo que proporciona el énfasis, es decir es lo que equivale a 'which'?  Así que:

> *se negó, una decisión que resultó desastrosa*

tendría un matiz distinto?

Pensaba que quizá se pueda usar 'cual' de algún modo

> *se negó, y cual decisión resultó desastrosa*

Pero no me parece bien...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93641/discussion-between-lambie-and-cerulean).

Comment: Related question at ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/498408/112436

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No hay en castellano una manera equivalente e igual de concisa de referirse a un antecedente como con este *which* en inglés. La forma más parecida requiere una subordinada extra:

> he refused, which decision proved disastrous
>   *se negó, una decisión la cual resultó desastrosa*

Esta construcción suena afectada y artificial; lo natural sería usar *que* en vez de *la cual*.

Hay una alternativa menos literal pero sin la misma gramática:

> *se negó, lo cual resultó una decisión desastrosa*

Aquí corresponde decir *lo cual*, con pronombre neutro, porque *lo cual* no se refiere a *decisión* sino al hecho expresado por *se negó*.

Comment: No existe como frase: he refused, which decision proved disastrous. Es un fragmento que no tiene ningún sentido en inglés.

Comment: Interesting discussion here: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=606 (off-topic here, but I was curious).

Comment: Yes,those uses with "which thoughts" and "which accusations" is only used today in legal language. Otherwise, which is just a relative pronoun: The games, where were very difficult, could not be bought in stores. And the sentence ***fragement*** given in the question is not grammatical in English.

Comment: @pablodf76. Thanks for the clues as to what this usage is called, 'relative determinative'.  We are now off-topic, but, as the source you provided indicates, this usage, while (as I said) somewhat rare and formal these days, is perfectly valid English, being used, as the text indicates, by contemporary authors as well.  As far as the usage only being in legal texts: David Foster Wallace is not a legal text, as far as I know.  And the sentence given in the Oxford dictionary, 'He refused, which decision proved disastrous', while it relies on context to make sense, is a full and valid sentence.

Comment: @Cerulean Please provide the link to the Oxford dictionary. First, you said on your Mac, then you said El Gran Diccionário Español. Tell me: why can't I find it? except in these dodgy links: https://www.google.com/search?biw=1379&bih=680&ei=0-jaXIHBFs6e_QbRvpawCw&q=%22He+refused%2C+which+decision+proved+disastrous%22&oq=%22He+refused%2C+which+decision+proved+disastrous%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i302i39.16750.22885..23330...0.0..2.222.789.4j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.bNc4qdVC81Q

Comment: @Lambie -- It's simply the English/Spanish dictionary that's installed on my Mac, system 10.x.  That was the info provided, beyond that I don't know.  If anyone is interested, I started a conversation regarding this topic on the English language forum -- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/498408/can-anyone-give-me-examples-of-the-relative-determinative-which -- which is probably where we should continue this...

Comment: @Cerulean Why do you not believe that the fragment as is, is good English?

Comment: @Lambie -- _Why do you not believe that the fragment as is, is good English?_ --> I do believe it is good English.  Perhaps post any other questions to chat or to the discussion on the English language forum.

Comment: The antecedent must be a noun or noun phrase or a to +verb, not a sentence like: He refused. That sentence (He refused) is not grammatical as the antecedent for a which determiner. Did he accept the invitation? No, he refused it.Did he accept to do the work? No, he refused. But not: He refused, etc. Impossible.

Comment: Please continue this discussion in the proper forum.

Comment: In the discussion in languagelog you mention, **in which case** is cited as the most common usage. I'd translate that into Spanish as **en cuyo caso.** Do you think a simmilar translation (_se nego, cuya decisión resultó desastrosa_) would be appropiate here? It doesn't sound right to me as **cuya** seems to refer to the decision maker. However, I'm not to clear as to whom **cuyo** refers to in _cuyo caso_.

Comment: @Patricio - That is an interesting question, and I'd encourage you to post it in a separate question.

Comment: @aparente001 - I've just looked it up. The use of *cuyo* in *en cuyo caso* appears to be an archaism. See part 5 in DPD (1st ed.) http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=qhkCllDtXD6sM9mVT1

Comment: @Patricio - Archaism seems stronger than what your link says: "En la lengua actual ha quedado un resto de este valor de cuyo en la expresión 'en cuyo caso' ....  No se censura su empleo."  I've seen it, heard it, and used it.  It's got a special tone that you wouldn't want to use every day, but there are times it fits the bill.

Comment: @aparente001 -yeah, perhaps is too strong a word

Comment: @Patricio - My feeling about this -- as I said in my supplemental answer -- is that it's more common in formal language (essays, speeches, etc.) than in conversation.  I think that holds for both Spanish and English.

Comment: Es como una consecuencia?

Answer (score 2):

La traducción más cercana al original **y correcta en español** de:

> *He refused, **which decision** proved disastrous.*

Sería esta:

> Él rehusó, **la cual decisión** resultó desastrosa.

Este uso de *cual* como adjetivo relativo acompañando al sustantivo, es exactamente el mismo uso que el de ese *which* en inglés y, aunque infrecuente en español hoy día, se sigue considerando válido según podemos leer en el DPD:

> [**cual**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=HIfkupNx9D60DqyH9R)
>
> **2.2.** Aunque es hoy infrecuente, también puede usarse como adjetivo relativo antepuesto a un sustantivo: *«Estava en mi propósito de ir a Barçelona por la mar, en la cual ciudad me davan nuevas de que Sus Alteças estavan»* (RBastos *Vigilia* [Par. 1992]); *«La tercera razón es el fin último que movió al papa cuando concedió esos reinos de Indias a los reyes de España, el cual fin no fue otro [...] más que la predicación de la fe cristiana»* (Beuchot *Filósofos* [Méx. 1992]). Lo normal en la lengua actual es la posposición del relativo: *ciudad en la cual...*, *fin que no fue otro...*

Por supuesto, sería más normal en español decir:

> (Él) rehusó, (una) decisión que resultó desastrosa.

Igual que en inglés sería quizá también más normal decir:

> *He refused, a decision that proved disastrous.*

Comment: He refused, which decision proved disastrous. is not grammatical in English. He refused, a decision proved disastrous. Is grammatical and appositional.

Answer (score 2):

In that particular example I would use 'dicha' or 'tal'

> se negó, dicha decisión resultó desastrosa 
>  se negó, tal decisión
> resultó desastrosa

The way your dictionary translates it is also correct by using 'que' after 'decisión'

> se negó, decisión que resultó desastrosa

Answer (score 0):

*This is intended as a supplement to Pablo's answer.*

Let's start with

> Se negó, lo cual fue una decisión que resultó desastrosa.

(This is equivalent to "He refused, which was a decision that proved disastrous.")

There is a nice way of making it more concise:

> Se negó, decisión que resultó desastrosa.

(This is equivalent to "He refused, which decision proved disastrous," or "He refused -- a decision which proved disastrous.")

Note that this concise version is more common in formal language (essays, speeches, etc.) than in conversation.

If you want to practice making sentences with this pattern, you'll need to come up with a word that describes, or sums up, the first clause.  Here are some more examples, with the summing up word in bold:

Cuando empezó a tener problemas con las encías, el  niño empezó a lavarse los dientes diez veces al día, **práctica** que agudizó la inflamación de las encías.

La maestra de matemáticas les encargaba, a diario, 40 problemas del mismito tipo, **tarea** que le hizo cuestionar su predilección por la materia.

---

In a comment, you had a similar but slightly different example:

> It rained all day, during which time we played cards.

In principle you could say

> Llovió todo el día, tiempo durante el cual jugamos a las cartas.

But I don't recommend this.  It just sounds unnecessarily pretentious.  However, sometimes it is helpful.  I'll try to come up with such an example, where it is worthwhile:

> La organización X estuvo activa desde (fecha m) hasta (fecha n), **periodo** en el cual se presentaron varios proyectos de ley que formaron el fundamento de la política actual de anti-discriminación.

You could substitute "durante" for "en."  The effect is the same.

Again, I put the summing up descriptive word in bold to make things clearer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93758/discussion-on-answer-by-aparente001-cual-seria-la-traduccion-correcta-para-whi).

Answer (score 0):

- ¿Cuál sería la traducción correcta para 'which"?

he refused, which decision proved disastrous

- "**se negó, decisión que resultó desastrosa**"
- "se negó, decisión la cual resultó desastrosa"
- "se negó, lo cual resultó una decisión desastrosa"

---

En Español, el pronombre relativo compuesto el cual, la cual, lo cual, los cuales, las cuales, se usa siempre con antecedente explícito.

Cuando el antecedente relativo es una oración, es obligado utilizar la forma neutra, **"lo cual"**: «Era feo, tosco y bruto pero poseía dinero, lo cual le facilitaba el éxito entre las mujeres". "*se negó, lo cual resultó una decisión desastrosa*". Sin embargo, en casi todas las circunstancias y entornos  esta admitido y puede utilizarse en su lugar el relativo **"que"**, ya que es mucho más frecuente en el habla corriente del Español;

- "**se negó, decisión que resultó desastrosa**".

---

No obstante, el uso de "*cual*" es obligatorio en los siguientes  4 casos:

1 -  En complementos partitivos: «Dijo que tiene otros cuatro hijos, dos de los cuales son gemelos» (Universal [Ven.] 2.1.89). Sí puede sustituirse cual por el relativo que si el complemento partitivo antecede al núcleo: Tiene cuatro hijos, de los que dos son gemelos.

2 - En cláusulas absolutas: «"Yo no puedo luchar sola contra Thérèse [...]". Dicho lo cual, Evelyne se volvió bruscamente y se refugió en mi pecho» (Cano Abismo [Col. 1991]).

3 - Como término de locuciones preposicionales, como a consecuencia de, gracias a, a pesar de, etc.: «Fernando sufrió graves heridas a consecuencia de las cuales falleció posteriormente» (León Lecuona [Cuba 1995]); «Melanie seguía perdiendo peso, a pesar de lo cual el terapeuta insistía en no obligarla con la comida» (Rausch Dietas [Arg. 1996]).

4 - Como término de la preposición según: «El conductismo se basa en el principio según el cual todo tipo de conductas son aprendidas» (Saiz Ansiedad [Esp. 1993]). Solo si el complemento introducido por según está regido por el verbo de la subordinada relativa y el pronombre relativo antecede inmediatamente al verbo, el relativo cual puede sustituirse por "*que*".

La fuente: el DPD

P.D La frase - "**se negó, decisión que resultó desastrosa**" que da tu diccionario, desde mi punto de vista es la mejor.

Answer (score -2):

he refused, which decision proved disastrous

is not grammatical in English as written and would also not be grammatical in Spanish: rechazó, una decisión que resultó desastrosa.

Hay que rechazar algo, una cosa o una acción.

> ***He refused to go, which decision proved disastrous***. That is not grammatical. You can add a which determiner clause there because what
> is being refused is the going. **You need the full antecedent.**
>
> And it is the same thing as:
> ***He refused to go, a decision which proved disastrous.***

Ergo, the translation into Spanish is:

> Rechazó ir, una decisión que resultó desastrosa.

So, the which is not translated in this case, other than by apposition and the noun with the determine una and que.

What I have said about the verb refuse is "proven" by the exercises for ELL on this site:

[sentences with refuse in English](http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/refuse/1.html)

Please note how the sentences are structured. refuse with nothing after it, refuse with a to-verb phrase and refuse with a direct object.

I am not going to post all the sentences. But those are the basic patterns for refuse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93810/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-lambie).